# How to convert custom proptype in react jsx to typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-proptypes

I am converting my project files from jsx to tsx. For normal proptypes, I am able to provide equivalent in interface. But for custom Proptypes I am unable to do the same. please find below the example scenario to get an idea.

## AppContainer.jsx

```
    const AppContainer = (props) => {
  return <div>{/*my component*/}</div>;
};

const customPropCheck = (props, propName, componentName) => {
  if (
    (props.primaryValue && !props.secondaryValue) ||
    (!props.primaryValue && props.secondaryValue)
  ) {
    return new Error(`Error for ${componentName} `);
  }
  return null;
};
AppContainer.defaultProps = {
  primaryValue: null,
  secondaryValue: null,
};

AppContainer.propTypes = {
  primaryValue: customPropCheck,
  secondaryValue: customPropCheck,
};

export default AppContainer;
```

## AppContainer.tsx

```
interface AppContainerProps {
  primaryValue: Error | null;
  secondaryValue: Error | null;
}

const AppContainer = ({
  primaryValue = null,
  secondaryValue = null,
}: AppContainerProps) => {
  return <div>{/*my component*/}</div>;
};

export default AppContainer;
```

How do i implement customPropCheck in my tsx? Is there any way Or do I have to copy same propType implementation in my tsx file ie:

```
AppContainer.propTypes = {
    primaryValue: customPropCheck,
    secondaryValue: customPropCheck 
}
```

Comment: Maybe [this](https://blog.logrocket.com/comparing-typescript-and-proptypes-in-react-applications/#:~:text=generate%20the%20other.-,1.%20InferProps,-InferPropTypes%20from%20%40types) could help you out

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript can help with the *type* aspect of `prop-types`, but if you want custom checks like yours to be applied when the props are specified (instead of later when the component is rendered), you still need `prop-types` to do that.

As far as I can tell, there's no special problem using it. The types of the parameters in `customPropCheck` are `AppContainerProps`, `keyof AppContainerProps`, and `string` respectively.

```typescript
const customPropCheck = (props: AppContainerProps, propName: keyof AppContainerProps, componentName: string) => {
    if (
        (props.primaryValue && !props.secondaryValue) ||
        (!props.primaryValue && props.secondaryValue)
    ) {
        return new Error(`Error for ${componentName} `);
    }
    return null;
};
```

Then you just assign to the function (I was expecting this to be a problem, but it doesn't seem to be):

```typescript
AppContainer.defaultProps = {
    primaryValue: null,
    secondaryValue: null,
};

AppContainer.propTypes = {
    primaryValue: customPropCheck,
    secondaryValue: customPropCheck,
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=15&ssc=1&pln=34&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4BYAKCuADsYkpN0k4BBMMAYQnpTsYAFHGADOcAN5UAkGCigUUAJ4A1FABsArkgBccAKJQcUOAB84tTevUVK00UjS8AJotUbtew8bMWrNqgBfKionWlF4Dm5eGH5aRjgAXjgACik7OQVlNS1WZMtrABoZBzDXbI88vyKgvSiePgEoYQgxAEokgD5JGSIYTShaOAAeZ2AAN06JAHoAKhAlOCdwXiR6WenA4emxydtA21DeCKXNCNwW7gALRwBrJNS5VtE6zgbYpsvRQrgnsAA5FAgXRwW5IJQQTDsN4xOJCETfJa4SDxeiA4F6CLyWgAcw6iW66WkwChKRk0hSf1EADpMiA3DltHAAGTMuAAQip1NKLgZlQ6plM5JSnIRtPk9IquRZbK5PNo5XcuTaMg6ROkfQGQ3iAHcDEZoCkAAbeaBwTBmgAkEmWKLWMHRSECcCNbVs0mCdk1g2qAUoBxClHqsKa1OcSGYVhgXweRLpfNyegK6mKdnlisZIOTqYD1CDMMa8Sg4taABUlGAkOJknGJQnPKdziBLlwbmhbqn7I5eVKG2gzjALiJW3cc4dKEgAB6QWBwcOR9SRAsfIukIA)

The `defaultProps` part of that is conceptually redundant, you're specifying defaults in the destructuring in your component props, but again those will get applied once when the element is created, not repeatedly when the component for it gets rendered, so there might be an argument for keeping it (although your custom check doesn't rely on it, you'll see `undefined` instead of `null` but your checks don't care about the distinction).

Comment: Does it mean, there is no way to completely replace custom proptype implementation in typescript?

Comment: I think prop types are checked when props are passed to the component. In your updated code, I can see you are checking the condition inside the component. This part is bit tricky. Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @PrabhatKumar - You're right, I'd forgotten that. I've removed that part of the answer.

Comment: I think, not every propType (Custom one) can be converted to typing through typescript. React passes params "props, propName and componentname" to its customprop type function when props are type checked. Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @PrabhatKumar - I think you're right. I edited the answer a few minutes ago along those same lines.